# How do I break out of a loop while creating a string array when the max number of strings allowed is entered?

Tags: c

I am trying to print a list of friend names entered by the user. The max number of names that can be entered is 5. The user also has option to enter < 5. I don't understand why I am unable to break out of the loop when 5 names have been entered? Thanks

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main(void) {
    
  char namesArray[5][100]; //5 = number of names while 100 = the maximum length of the name

  int x, y;
  char yesNo;
  int counter = 0;

 do {
    for (x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
    printf("\nEnter a friends name: ");
    scanf(" %s", &namesArray[x][0]);
    counter++;

    printf("\nWould you like to enter another friends name? Y or N: ");
    scanf(" %c", &yesNo);
    if (yesNo == 'N')
    break;
    }
  } while (yesNo == 'Y' || counter == 5);


 if (yesNo == 'N' || counter == 5){
    for (x = 0; x < counter; x++) {
    printf("\n\n%s", namesArray[x]);
    }
  }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: Change `scanf(" %s", &namesArray[x][0]);` into  `scanf(" %s", namesArray[x]);` - it does the same thing

Comment: The `do/while` and the `for` loop are fighting each other. Use only a single loop construct there. For example: `do { ... } while (yesNo == 'Y' && counter < 5);`

Comment: Also, the `if (yesNo == 'N' || counter == 5)` is wrong and won't print anything if the user enters less than 5 friends. Remove that completely and let the `for` loop after it do its job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question:

Your do-while loop never ends because `counter` is never `5` when the condition is reached.
You increase `counter` inside of the for-loop which ends when `x` is `5`. So `counter` will be `6` when you leave the first for-loop. (Because when the loop starts `x` is `0` and you increase `counter` to `1`)

Thus the change to make your code work would be to change the do-while condition to:

```
 while (yesNo == 'Y' || counter < 5);
```

The better solution would be to change the code a bit to get rid of the do-while loop entirely.
You can just have the for-loop (to make sure a maximum of 5 names will be entered) and add the condition for the `yesNo` to it so you can break-out before 5 names are entered.

Answer (score 1):

All of the other comments are true, so you probably want something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    
    char namesArray[5][100]; // 5 = number of names, 100 = max length of each
    char yesNo;
    int counter;

    for (counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++) {
        printf("\nEnter a friends name: ");
        scanf(" %99s",namesArray[counter]);
        printf("\nWould you like to enter another friends name? Y or N? ");
        scanf(" %c", &yesNo);
        if (yesNo == 'N')
            break;
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < counter; x++)
        printf("\n\n%s",namesArray[x]);
    exit(0);
}
```